# Custom mocking for testing with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching, pytest-mock

I have a code base (shown below), with a **src** directory containing the code, that I have developed, alongside with some supporting Third Party libs in **tp** directory.

```
.
├── src
│   ├── f.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── tp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── sim.py
│
└── tests
```

```py
# contents of src/f.py

#!/usr/bin/python
from tp.sim import sim

def somefunc():
    sim()
```

```py
# contents of tp/sim.py

#!/usr/bin/python

def sim():
    print("Hello, I'm in sim.sim()")
```

I intend to write tests for the code inside *src* directory. As its visible with the sample files, the code in **src** directory relies on the files in **tp**. For majority of functions in **tp**, I intend to `monkeypatch` them for testing. A example of the test file is shown below.

```py
   1 #!/usr/bin/python
   2
   3
   4 import src
   5 from src.f import somefunc
   6 from tp.sim import sim
   7
   8
   9 def deco(func):
  10     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
  11         print("I'm inside wrapper")
  12         func(*args, **kwargs)
  13
  14     return wrapper
  15
  16
  17 sim = deco(sim)
  18
  19 # setattr(src.f, 'sim', sim)
  20 somefunc()
```

In the above code, when *monkeypatching* the `tp.sim.sim`, doesn't affect the behaviour for `src.f.somefunc` (line 20). And only when we explicity patch the function `sim` in the namespace `src.f.sim` (line 19), do we see the *patched* function.

I have multiple files inside **src** directory, which `import` files from within **tp** directory and from **src** which in turn `import` from **tp** files.

My question primarily is, How do I ensure that my monkeypatched functions is always the one used during my testing (i.e. if I patch `tp.sim.sim()` with `mysim()` in my test setup, then all the test in that scope always see `mysim()`)

Comment: Why `from tp.sim import sim` in `tp/sim.py`? It's importing itself, which looks strange to me.

Comment: @JulienPalard, That line was error in edit.

Answer (score 0):

If your tested code imports:

```py
from tp.sim import sim
```

The `f` module will have a global `sim` name pointing to the `sim` function. Changing `sim` in the globals of `tp.sim` won't magically update the global name `sim` in the module `f`, so `f.sim` will always point to the real function.

So if you want to monkeypatch the `sim` function anyway without changing your import you can try to patch the global `sim` name of the `f` module, meaning: `src.f.sim`.

It would be easier to understand by changing the import in `f` as:

```py
from tp import sim
```

In which case `src.f` gets a `sim` global name pointing to the `sim` module, module in which function can get modified by your current patching method. No duplicated `sim` function name, no surprises.